# Is it adequate to use CMS for small admin panel app?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I need to code a small admib panel that should get and display statistics from remote servers. The main problem here is that I need to do that ASAP. So the main question here is: to use CMS or not? I'm almost sure that deploying something big like Joomla or Drupal will not be quick. Still, maybe there's something easier that matces the following conditions.

- has implemented security stuff (secure login, sessions and etc);
- has implemented user/groups/privileges mechanism;
- has an abbility of adding users for Super Administrator.

**UPD.** framework instead of CMS will do as well.

Comment: Deploying the CMS you mentioned without the ability to manage content would not only defy it's purpose, but you would waste so much server resources. Personally I would have build my own mechanism. However, I'm pretty sure there are mechanisms on the net that will help you.

Comment: http://webdesignledger.com/tools/10-simple-and-light-weight-cms-solutions this blogpost has a few leightweight cms featured you may want to check it out.

Comment: I think it would be better, if you use framework instead of cms.
I recommend [slimframework][1] for its simplicity, still you get all security stuff, and its really quick to build an app with that.


  [1]: http://www.slimframework.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with `codeIgniter` ? If yes then it is what you want.

[Bonfire](http://cibonfire.com/)

It is a `CMS` with full time functionality of `user/groups/privileges mechanism` and many more.